# Does a Neo4j application exist in a jar or what?

Tags: neo4j

I'm trying to understand what form a Neo4j app would typically take, particularly one using the core and traversal APIs.  Would it be a jar or some other archive that's loaded as a Neo4j extension?  A Tomcat servlet that connects to Neo4j?  Something else I haven't thought of?

Apologies if this is a dumb question.  My Google-fu is weak today.  I tried to understand by looking for a Neo4j "Hello, World!", but they all seem to use embedded Neo4j, which is not what I'm after...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `neo4j-kernel` JAR technically contains everything you need for creating a neo4j database. What neo4j really is is just an efficient way of storing the data you want into a file. The `kernel` JAR contains all the necessary information on how to write your nodes and relationships to disk.

When you start a neo4j server, this is really just a web app that accepts RESTful commands and console input to write information to the filesystem. You can use some of the other JARs to interact RESTfully with neo4j though.

Comment: For interacting with Neo4j-Server from Java, check out the JDBC driver: https://github.com/neo4j-contrib/neo4j-jdbc/tree/2.0

Comment: You sound like you know what you're talking about, but my question is probably clumsy.  So, say I wanted to write a web app that uses Neo4j, like maybe a game or an issue tracker or something.  What I'm getting at is, what would that app likely be?  An ordinary Tomcat app?  A Neo4j extension?

Comment: I understand your answer better after re-reading the relevant section in the O'Reilly Graph Databases book.  My confusion was that I thought there was more than one API for accessing a _remote_ Neo4j server.  But the core and traversal APIs are only for embedded, right?  If my app were separate from the Neo4j cluster, it could be anything, but it would talk to the database using the REST API.  (The book also says that embedded databases can be clustered, but points out that keeping the app and database separate allows the database cluster to be scaled independently of the app server cluster.)

Comment: That app could be anything, a javascript, python, ruby, java app. It would use a database driver to connect to Neo4j and read and write data to the database. For Java best right now is the JDBC driver (imho) for the JVM there are also drivers for scala (AnormCypher), clojure (neocons) and others. see http://neo4j.org/drivers

Comment: You can cluster both the server and embedded (even mix it). Remotely you'd use Cypher in most cases.